# Tax implications on international wire transfer

Tags: united-states, taxes, international-transfer

I have a retired US citizen brother who decided to live overseas after his retirement. He and his wife's social security checks is automatically deposited in a US bank account. He has asked me to withdraw $35000 that has accumulated and wire transfer the amount to him. Is there any implication or tax liability that I should be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

There's no tax on wire transfer, but it would be easier on everyone if he would wire himself from his own account. Withdrawing money, depositing to your account and then wiring back to him may raise some flags with FinCEN and IRS with questions about money laundering or gift taxes. Why do you want to complicate things?

Comment: The problem is that his bank does not wire transfer internationally therefore I had to do it this way. Thanks for your answer Littleadv

Answer (score 1):

Better 7 years late than never... hopefully, you were able to wire the money to your brother overseas. I find it rare that even a small regional bank doesn't offer international wire transfers thru an intermediary bank. Most banks in the US seems to use Citi for international wires. As far as tax implications, it's hard to tell, but I'm pretty sure a large transaction would trigger some sort of report from your bank to relevant tax authorities. Whether the tax authorities act on it, or audit you on it, is a different matter and impossible to know/answer.

There's nothing nefarious in helping your brother, but using your personal bank account as a money transfer service for your brother is prob not wise for the reasons above.

For posterity, I'll give you the best solution IMO:

- Research for a better bank that offers international wires (any of the Big Banks names will prob have this), and ask your brother/his wife to open an account online with said "better bank" in the US. Fund the new account by transferring that retirement money to it, and then have them wire the money to themselves from there. Have them close the account after a few weeks. Done. Zero risk for you.
- If you're feeling extra helpful to your brother and his wife, (and they're the kind that need to be hand-held for these kind of things): you could always ask your brother to give you a power of attorney to open a new joint account, which you will open in both of your names, and again fund the new account with their retirement money, and wire it. Close the joint account when done.
- Another option, if they don't need the full $35k wired all at once, I'd break it up into 4-5 chunks and send it via a wire transfer service like Wise or Remitly. These services are actually faster and less complicated than a SWIFT wire transfer, and likely would help them avoid having to open a new account at a BigBank just to wire money abroad. The advantage of this method is that you can more or less try to pick a day where there's a favorable exchange rate and lock it in.